# where can I see the data captured by kofax once it goes through export?

Tags: kofax

When processing documents, it goes through all phases. Once it goes through export it generates an error:

> Export Error: Script #1 (PROD-MDCR Strp Search) [0 Updating the new
>   document failed.]

What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the error, you need to work with the person or company that wrote that particular export connector ("PROD-MDCR Strp Search"), which is not made by Kofax.

As to where you would "see the data captured by [Kofax Capture] once it goes through export," this would depend on what happens at export: If it is successful, then the batch is deleted and what remains is whatever your export connector exported which depends entirely on which export connector and what configuration.

If it is not successful, then the data is still in the batch.  You can set the batch to the Quality Control module to view the images.  You cna set the batch to the Validation or KTM Validation modules to view field data, though the specifics depend on your configuration.

Comment: IMO the best way is to interactively debug the Kofax Export Connector in Visual Studio while it is processing the batch of documents.  Then you can set breakpoints in code, examine the data in the batch (ReleaseData object) and see every detail of the error and the conditions leading to it. To set up interactive debugging of your Kofax Export Connector, you will need the source code for the export connector and to configure a system with Visual Studio on it. It's a bit involved to set up, but once you have it, it's game-changing.  If you meet the prerequisites, give it a shot.